# Tapestry 5 Still Requires .page or .jwc files?

Tags: java, annotations, tapestry

A company I work for uses Tapestry 3.0.3 for their product. This code has many *.page* and *.jwc* files. While wanting to ease up the configuration overhead - would it be possible to make the upgrade-effort to Tapestry 5 in hopes that using Java annotations (compiling code) could replace all these *.page* and *.jwc* files (non compiling text)?

In short; can Java annotations be used in Tapestry 5 to remove all Tapestry 3.0.3 *.page* and *.jwc* files? If yes, I would appreciate any advise, guides or resources on how to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy upgrade path from Tapestry 3 or Tapestry 4 to Tapestry 5.

I can say that *every* aspect of Tapestry 5 is easier, simpler, faster, and more fun than Tapestry 3.

And specifically yes, there's no XML in Tapestry 5 outside of the template files. It's entirely driven by classes, annotations, and naming conventions.